# SQL- How can I group items together based on a value in another column?

Tags: sql, excel, group-by, grouping, coalesce

Consider the below data set. How can I combine column 2 into one row, and separate column 2 into either separate columns, OR one column? 
I'll show what I have, vs what I need..Thank you.

Here's what I currently have:

```
column 0, column 1 , column 2
1       ,  Dog      , Hello 
1       ,  Dog      , I like dogs
2       ,  Koala    , fur
2       ,  Koala    , cuddly
2       ,  Koala    , lazy
3       ,  Puppy    , small
3       ,  Puppy    , adolescent
4       ,  Spaghetti, taste good
4       ,  Spaghetti, italy
4       ,  Spaghetti, mama mia
4       ,  Spaghetti,fugeddaboudit
```

and here's what I want 
(Ignore the space I have no idea what happened)

```
column 0, column 1 , column 2
1       ,  Dog      , Hello , I like dogs    
2       ,  Koala    , fur, cuddly, lazy
3       ,  Puppy    , small, adolescent
4       ,  Spaghetti, taste good, Italy, mama mia, fugeddaboudit
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use TSQL STUFF function. Try this query. Works fine on SQL Server.

```
   SELECT [column0]
  ,[column1]
  ,[column2] = STUFF((SELECT ',' + [column2] 
          FROM [tablename] t1
          WHERE t1.[column0] = t2.[column0]
          FOR XML PATH (''))
         , 1, 1, '') from [tablename] t2
GROUP BY [column0]
  ,[column1]
```